# Socket.IO: TypeError: Object has no method packet

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I faced with problem with global emitting events with Socket.IO.
**That's a server-side error btw instead of [#489](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/issues/489).**

Cases when error occur

```
nsp = io.of('/namespace');
nsp.emit('hello', 'there');

io.emit('hello', 'there');

io.sockets.emit('hello', 'there');

var needed_namespace = '/my_namespace';
io.nsps[needed_namespace].emit('hello', 'there');
```

In every case i have the following error:

```
TypeError: Object function (key) {
    if (!this[key]) {
      return this[key] = 1;
    } else {
        return this[key] += 1;
    }
} has no method 'packet'
at /Users/nr/Git/lt-connection/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-adapter/index.js:125:28
at Encoder.encode (/Users/nr/Git/lt-connection/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-adapter/node_modules/socket.io-parser
at Adapter.broadcast (/Users/nr/Git/lt-connection/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-adapter/index.js:107:16)
at Namespace.emit (/Users/nr/Git/lt-connection/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:218:18)
at SocketTransport.global.SocketTransport.SocketTransport.deliver (/Users/nr/Git/lt-connection/lib/prototype/socket.coffee:40:26)
at SocketTransport.global.SocketTransport.SocketTransport.emit (/Users/nr/Git/lt-connection/lib/prototype/socket.coffee:11:6)
at SocketTransport.global.SocketTransport.SocketTransport.send_from_http (/Users/nr/Git/lt-connection/lib/prototype/socket.
at Object.exports.routes.handlers.post (/Users/nr/Git/lt-connection/lib/http_server/routes/socket_router.coffee:9:11)
at apply (/Users/nr/Git/lt-connection/node_modules/director/lib/director/router.js:444:19)
at _every (/Users/nr/Git/lt-connection/node_modules/director/lib/director/router.js:28:9)
at [object Object].Router.invoke (/Users/nr/Git/lt-connection/node_modules/director/lib/director/router.js:450:5)
at parseAndInvoke (/Users/nr/Git/lt-connection/node_modules/director/lib/director/http/index.js:175:10)
at [object Object].Router.dispatch (/Users/nr/Git/lt-connection/node_modules/director/lib/director/http/index.js:198:7)
at /Users/nr/Git/lt-connection/lib/http_server/index.coffee:31:13
at IncomingForm.<anonymous> (/Users/nr/Git/lt-connection/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:104:9)
at IncomingForm.emit (events.js:92:17)
at IncomingForm._maybeEnd (/Users/nr/Git/lt-connection/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:551:8)
at QuerystringParser.parser.onEnd (/Users/nr/Git/lt-connection/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:446:10)
at QuerystringParser.end (/Users/nr/Git/lt-connection/node_modules/formidable/lib/querystring_parser.js:25:8)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/nr/Git/lt-connection/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:129:30)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:92:17)
at _stream_readable.js:938:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

Actual code where error occur (it compiled from CoffeeScript, sorry for readability):

```
deliver: function(message, channel, namespace, socket) {
    var err;
    socket = this.get_namespace(namespace, socket);
    message = this.prepage_message(message);
    try {
        if (channel != null) {
        //error occur here (line 125:28 from error stack)
        return socket.emit(channel, message);
    }
        //also error will be here when 'channel' not passed to '.deliver()'
        return socket.emit(message);
    } catch (_error) {
        err = _error;
        return console.warn('Something may be wrong: ' + err.stack);
    }
},

get_namespace: function(ns, socket) {
    var namespace, _ref;
    if (socket != null) {
        return socket;
    }
    namespace = null;
    if ((namespace = this.namespaces[ns]) != null) {
        return namespace;
    } else if ((namespace = (_ref = this.io.nsps) != null ? _ref[namespace] : void 0) != null) {
        return this.namespaces[ns] = namespace;
    } else {
        return this.create_namespace(ns);
    }
},

create_namespace: function(ns) {
    var socket;
    if (ns == null) {
        ns = '/';
    }
    socket = this.io;
    if (ns !== '/') {
        socket = socket.of(ns);
    }
    this.namespaces[ns] = socket;
    return socket;
}
```

Any solutions? Or may be i doing it wrong?
Btw two of these cases are listed in [official docs](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#server#emit)

Also there is an issue on GitHub: [#1747](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/issues/1747)

**UPD:**

One more stack-trace:

```
  socket.io-parser encoding packet {"type":2,"data":["hello","world"],"nsp":"/"} +0ms
  socket.io-parser encoded {"type":2,"data":["hello","world"],"nsp":"/"} as 2["hello","world"] +0ms

/Users/nr/Git/lt-connection/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-adapter/index.js:125
        if (socket) socket.packet(encodedPackets, true, flags.volatile);
                           ^
TypeError: Object function (key) {
    if (!this[key]) {
      return this[key] = 1;
    } else {
      return this[key] += 1;
    }
  } has no method 'packet'
  at /Users/nr/Git/lt-connection/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-adapter/index.js:125:28
  at Encoder.encode (/Users/nr/Git/lt-connection/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-adapter/node_modules/socket.io-parser/index.js:110:5)
  at Adapter.broadcast (/Users/nr/Git/lt-connection/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-adapter/index.js:107:16)
  at Namespace.emit (/Users/nr/Git/lt-connection/node_modules/socket.io/lib/namespace.js:218:18)
  at Server.(anonymous function) [as emit] (/Users/nr/Git/lt-connection/node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js:338:16)
  at SocketTransport.global.SocketTransport.SocketTransport.deliver (/Users/nr/Git/lt-connection/lib/prototype/socket.coffee:40:15)
  at SocketTransport.global.SocketTransport.SocketTransport.emit (/Users/nr/Git/lt-connection/lib/prototype/socket.coffee:11:6)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all. Problem solved and was caused by my app and modyfied prototype of `Object`:

```
global.Object.prototype.increment = function(key) {
    if(!this[key]){
        this[key] = 1;
    }else{
        this[key] += 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to look at this problem with setInterval? It may be because of different context.

https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/issues/489

You are using an object (class?) to store your methods, so it may be in bad context.

Comment: Yeah, that's the class wrapper for Socket.IO. But as you can see in my code there is no setTimeout. How my class context may affect context of socket? And i should update question. Error on the server side.

Comment: Btw i use socket.io instance with it's native context without any modifications. I mean there's nothing like `socket.emit.bind(ctx)` in my code. Also there is no constructions like `setTimeout(socket.emit, 1000)`.

Comment: Aren't you emmiting to non-existing namespace? I mean : var needed_namespace = '/my_namespace';

Comment: No, now i just trying to emit messages to default namespace like `io.emit('hello', 'world')` or `io.sockets.emit('hello', 'world')` like in docs on socket.io. Inspecting tells that there is no difference between emitting to default nsp or non-existing. But my code handles non-existing nsps and it will create one if needed. Anyway there is no issues with namespaces. Problem is somewhere in `socket.io-adapter` but now i don't know where exactly.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling socket.io? Does is give you any errors?

Comment: Yes, i've reinstalled all my dependencies. No errors during installation. I've added one more stacktrace to the question.